# Can't pass mysqli object to class in PHP

Tags: php, object, mysqli

So I'm working on a simple user class in php, which has a class variable which contains the mysqli object, however I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in ***/classes/user.php on line X

I've checked everything, it should work, but it doesn't. Somehow. This is my code:

```
namespace bibliotheek;

class user
{
    private $mysql;

    private $logged_in = false;
    private $user_data = null;      //ARRAY: user_id, e-mail, password, bevoegdheid, naam, achternaam, adres, postcode, stad

    function __construct(\mysqli $mysql, $salt)
    {
        $this->mysql = $mysql;
    }

    public function login($email, $pass, $hash = false)
    {
        $email = $this->mysql->real_escape_string($email);
        if($hash == false)
            $pass  = sha1($this->salt.$pass);

        $query  = "SELECT *
                   FROM gebruikers
                   WHERE gebruikers.email = '$email' AND gebruikers.password = '$pass'";

        $result    = $this->mysql->query($query);
        $user_data = $result->fetch_assoc();

        if($user_data == null)
            return;

        $this->logged_in = true;
        $this->user_data = $user_data;
        $this->create_cookies($email, $pass);
    }
}
```

And this is how the mysqli object gets passed to the class:

```
$mysql  = new mysqli($cfg['mysql_server'], $cfg['username'], $cfg['password'], $cfg['database']);
$user   = new bibliotheek\user($mysql, $cfg['salt']);
```

the mysql login data is correct, I've made sure of that.

I must be missing something really obvious here, but I just can't see it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What gives `var_dump($this->mysql);` when you insert it just before that line with the error?

Comment: object(mysqli)#1 (17) {...} I omitted the stuff between brackets.

Comment: If the next line accesses that object, the error message does not match meaning you're looking at the wrong place or at the wrong place in time. You need to improve with your troubleshooting on this one.

Answer (score 0):

And this is how it should be

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysql  = new mysqli($cfg['mysql_server'], $cfg['username'], $cfg['password'], $cfg['database']);
if ( !$mysql )
{
    throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error()));
}
$user = new bibliotheek\user($mysql, $cfg['salt']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really f-ing stupid, I compacted my code a bit when I posted it on here and I left out this part:

```
    $this->mysql = $mysql;
    $this->mysql = $salt;
```

Kill me now.